# Keep getting errors when inputting a long string of numbers

Tags: java, string, numbers, space

So, my program is supposed to take the added form of the 16 digits used for a Visa or MasterCard. However, when I run it, the program will read a space as the end of the input.
For example: if i put in 1234 5678 9012 3444, the program will only add the sum of the numbers before I entered the space. Then, if i enter that whole string without spaces, it keeps giving me error codes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment4
{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sum = 0, number, modulo;
        String cardBrand;
        System.out.print("Visa or MasterCard? ");
        cardBrand = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter your 16 digit credit card number (no spaces): ");
        number = in.nextInt();

        while (number > 0)
        {

            int digit = number % 10;
            sum = sum + digit;
            number = number/10;

        }

        modulo = (sum % 10);

        if (cardBrand.equals("Visa"))
        {
            if (modulo == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("This is a valid Visa card. Good job.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("This is an invalid Visa card number.");
            }
        }
        else if (cardBrand.equals("MasterCard"))
        {
            if (modulo == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("This is a valid MasterCard.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("This is an invalid MasterCard card number.");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand this approach in general, but I do understand the errors.  in.nextInt() will only read up to the first space as you discovered (which makes this a bad approach already).  Second in.nextInt() reads an int, and int has a max value of 2^31-1 (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), or 2147483647, which isn't enough to hold the whole number.

Comment: Also, this isn't really accurate as far as determining the card type.  Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number.  It links to the MOD 10/Luhn algorithm and also includes the IIN numbers, which are what you need to use to determine the card type.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is limited to "2,147,483,647" so your number is out of range.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you really have to handle such large numbers.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I think the main thing my instructor wants is entering it like "1234 5567 3443 34343" so how do i get the program to read the whole line and not just the first 4 numbers

Comment: Then I'd suggest you read the numbers as strings, concat them, remove the spaces and start parsing then number afterwards.

Comment: OH. I think I remember how to do it now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine()` to read all the numbers then split them by the space.

```
String line = in.nextLine();
String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the next character is an int or not, as it is received, and sum up the ints. This way, you won't run into the issue of the size of int, as you are summing up each int as it is received.

```
   int sum = 0, number = 0, modulo;
   while(in.hasNext()){
     if(in.hasNextInt()){
     number = in.nextInt();
     sum = sum + number;
   }
   else{
     in.next();
   }
   modulo = sum % 10;
```

---

(`Ctrl + Z` or `Ctrl + D`, is the character to break the input sequence)

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**: Use `BigInteger` class. Its constructor input is `String`.

**Second Solution**: using `split` method in `String` class or using `StringTokenizer` class.
Bhesh wrote the `split` example. `StringTokenizer` example:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer ("1234 5678 9012 3444", " ");
st.nextToken() returns each part of your credit card number
```